# C++: About null characters

Tags: c++, operators, stdstring, double-quotes, null-character

There are two `string` variables, `m` and `n`:

```
#include <string>

string m = "0100700\0"
cout << m.size() << endl; // it prints: 7

string n;
n += "0100700"
n += '\0';
cout << n.size() << endl; // it prints: 8
```

I supposed that both had 8 characters, but `m` had only 7 characters and `n` had 8 characters. Why is this the case?

Comment: You do not need the explicit null character  as it is already there

Comment: I'm sorry for duplicate question. From now I try to solve my question by searching more carefully.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first thing to note is that `std::string` does not have a constructor that can infer the length of a string literal from the underlying array. What it has is a constructor that accepts a `const char*` and treats it as a null-terminated string. In doing so, it copies characters until it finds the first `\0`.

This is the constructor used in `string m = "0100700\0";`, which is why in the first case your string is of length 7. Note that there is no other way to get the length of a char array from a pointer to its first element.

In the second example, you add a character to a pre-existing `std::string` object of length 7. This increases the length to 8. If you were to iterate over the elements of the string, you would be able to see that this 8th element is `'\0'`.

```
for (auto c: n)
    if (c == 0) std::cout << "null terminator" << std::endl;
```

In order to initialize a string containing `'\0'` characters, you have options:

Use an initialization list:

```
std::string s{'a', 'b', '\0', 'd', 'e', '\0', 'g'};
```

Construct from a different container or array using `std::string`'s iterator constructor:

```
std::vector<char> v{'a', 'b', '\0', 'd', 'e', '\0', 'g'};
char c[] = {'a', 'b', '\0', 'd', 'e', '\0', 'g'};
const char* ps = "ab\0de\0g";

std::string s0(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
std::string s1(std::begin(c), std::end(c));
std::string s2(ps, ps + 8);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I understand why that happens. Is there any way to initialize std::string with string that contains null characters?

Comment: @carrot031 You can say for example `string s{'a', 'b', '\0', 'd', 'e', '\0', 'g'};`

Comment: Would be better to use the iterator constructor, as pointers are valid random-access iterators.

Answer (score 8):

In the 1st sample

```
 string m = "0100700\0";
```

The `string` variable is constructed from a character literal, and takes all characters up to the first `'\0'` character found.

The 2nd sample nevertheless shows, that you can add an arbitrary number of additional `'\0'` characters to a `std::string` and increase it's size.

---

To answer the question from your comment:

To initialize a string from a literal containing `'\0'`characters you cain either specify the count explicitly

```
string m("0100700\0",8);
```

or you can use the constructor using a `first` and `last` iterator:

```
 const char x[] = "0100700\0";
 string m(std::begin(x),std::end(x));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer! Is there any way smart way to initialize std::string with a string that contains null characters?

Comment: It looks more readable! I'll use that. I have been trying to make a c++ library for creating tar archives.